# Emulated Graphics on Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, intel

I've made an installation of ArchLinux on a new HP Envy 13 (i5-6200U). I've configured the distribution to use GNOME for the Graphics Display Manager (GDM).

My trouble is that for a new laptop, the graphics are painfully slow. On a previous Mint install on the same machine I was notified that the kernal was acting in Software Rendering Mode, and I feel this must be the case for my installation of Arch.

I've read the ArchWiki and it states Intel chipsets are expected to be 'plug-and-play'. The graphics are working (after all I am making this post from the laptop) but it struggles to play fullscreen video and shaders execute very slowly. I've not touched my `Xorg.conf.d`; maybe this could be the issue? My laptop screen also comes up as an 'Unknown Display' within *Displays*.

To confirm, running `glxinfo | grep render` confirms I'm using `llvmpipe`.

Comment: There are some known problems with skylake chips. Try adding `i915.preliminary_hw_support=1` to your kernel boot line.

Comment: @don_crissti That was fast! Amazing. Just to check, will this entry work in the file `/boot/loader/entries/arch.conf` that I select at the bootloader? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners'_guide#Install_a_boot_loader

Comment: Yes, you can append it to your existing `options` line but for a one-shot [press `e` when the menu appears and add the parameters to the end of the string](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_parameters#systemd-boot).

Comment: @don_crissti Absolutely unbelievable. Thank you so much.